# How to implement client-server interactions in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, server, client-server, iot

I have data on multiple files. I want to simulate federated learning, which is basically :
having the datasets on edge devices

```
initialisation of the server
initialisation of all client models with the same random weights 

for each round in range(R):

   for each client in client_list:

      client does :
      uploading weights from a server
      training neural networks locally with those weights
      returning the new weights to the server.

   server update its weights by doing a mean of the weights returned by the clients.
```

I have a file client.py with a class with all the methods the client needs : doing rounds of training and returning the new weights, evaluating the model over a train set, updating the learning rate.

I have a file server.py with all the methods needed for the server : updating the weights

I want to simulate this with first of all two computers, but I don't know anything about client-server architecture

Thank you by advance for all the insights you will give me, and have a nice day :)

Comment: FIrst of all, you don't need two computers to apply the client-server connection. Second of all, here is the [hello world](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) example of the client-server connection using Flask. Try to understand it very well and take it from there

Comment: It seems to me you want [Horovod](https://github.com/horovod/horovod)